# wxpython setting frame menubar from panel

Tags: wxpython, panel, frame, menubar

I have a separate file for main app (`f.py`) and separate file for a panel (`p.py`). I am setting a `Menubar` to `Frame` from within the `Panel`. Here is my working code:

**f.py**

```
import wx
import p

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Checking Menubar from external Panel")

        mainPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        mainPanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Color(0, 255, 0))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainPanel.SetSizer(sizer)

        subPanel = p.MyPanel(parent=mainPanel)
        sizer.Add(subPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)

#         subPanel.createMenuBar()

        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**p.py**

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=-1)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Color(255, 0, 0))

        self.createMenuBar()

    def createMenuBar(self):
        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        self.mnuFile = wx.Menu()
        self.mnuFile.Append(id=1, text="&New")
        self.mnuFile.Append(id=1, text="&Open")
        self.mnuFile.Append(id=1, text="E&xit")

        self.menuBar.Append(menu=self.mnuFile, title="&File")
        self.GetTopLevelParent().SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)
```

Above code adds a `Menubar` to `Frame`. But the `Panel` is not getting full size on output window. Here is the output image:

[image: <code>Panel</code> not getting full size]

Now, if I call `createMenu` function of `Panel` from within `Frame` (by uncommenting `subPanel.createMenuBar()` line from `f.py` and commenting `self.createMenuBar()` line from `p.py`) it gives output as desired. Here is the output image in which `Panel` covers full `Frame`:

[image: <code>Panel</code> covers full <code>Frame</code>]

I am not able to understand the reason why setting `Menubar` from within `Panel` disturbs the size of it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to to call **Layout()** on your sizer object:

```
import wx
import p

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Checking Menubar from external Panel")

        mainPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        mainPanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Color(0, 255, 0))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainPanel.SetSizer(sizer)

        subPanel = p.MyPanel(parent=mainPanel)
        sizer.Add(subPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)

#         subPanel.createMenuBar()

        self.Show()
        sizer.Layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Personally, I don't really see a reason to add a single panel on top of another panel. That just adds unneeded complexity. Here's a shorter version:

```
import wx
import p

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Checking Menubar from external Panel")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        mainPanel = p.MyPanel(parent=self)
        sizer.Add(mainPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You will note that I don't need to even call Layout() on this second version because theirs only one panel and it automatically takes up all the space. Also note that I changed your call from **wx.PySimpleApp** to **wx.App(False)**. PySimpleApp is deprecated.

Comment: Actually I am creating multiple `subPanels` which are displayed full screen with show/hide animation. I have a single `mainPanel` so that I can handle all `subPanel`'s container such way. 
Thanks for providing info for `wx.PySimpleApp` deprecation.